# React Navigation - custom goBack goes to different Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My code setup is like so, using React Native & React Navigation v6:

```
Tab Navigator
 - Stack A
   - Screen 1
 - Stack B
   - Screen 1
 - Stack C
    - Screen 1
    - Screen 2
    - Screen 3
```

When I navigate to from Screen A1 -> C1 -> C2 and use `navigation.goBack()`, I end up back at screen A1 from C2. I'd expect to be go back to C1.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong here. The code:

TabNavigator.js

```js
import 'ScreenA' from './Screens/ScreenA'
import 'ScreenB' from './Screens/ScreenB'
import { StackC } from './Stack'

const TabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"
                   screenOptions={{
                     header: (props) => <Header {...props} />
                   }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Stack A" component={ScreenA} initialParams={{ type: 'Stack A' }} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Stack B" component={ScreenB} initialParams={{ type: 'Stack B' }} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Stack C" component={StackC} options={{ tabBarButton: () => null }} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Stack.js

```js
import 'ScreenC1' from './Screens/ScreenC1'
import 'ScreenC2' from './Screens/ScreenC2'
import 'ScreenC3' from './Screens/ScreenC3'

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

export const StackC = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false, animation: 'none'}}
                     initialRouteName="C1"
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="C1" component={ScreenC1}  />
      <Stack.Screen name="C2" component={ScreenC2} />
      <Stack.Screen name="C3" component={ScreenC3} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

EDIT: It's worth noting that I have a custom back button in the Header and when I view the routes stack there, it always prints the same output not matter where I navigate... but if I print the route stack within the C2 screen it's there. So it seems there is a disconnect between my custom back button and the actual screen.

Header.js

```js
const Header = () => {
  const routes = navigation.getState()?.routes
  console.log('routes', routes.map(route => route.name) // ALWAYS prints [ A1, B1, Stack C]
  return (
    <View>
      {navigation.canGoBack() && <Text onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>{"< Back"}</Text >}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Navigating pages doesn't change the output in the Header but the same console.log() in screen C1 prints:

```
// [ C1, C2 ]
```

So its correct in screen C2 but not in the Header.. why is this?

Comment: Why the logic in the Stack component? Why not mount all the stacks as screens and navigate to the right stack? Either way, please share how you're navigating between stacks and screens.

Comment: @Abe yes you're right, unnecessary. I simplified the structure to the above, but still same issue. Its worth noting that I have a custom back button in the Header and when I view the routes stack there, its missing screen C2. but if I print the route stack within the C2 screen it's there. So it seems there a disconnect from my custom back button and the actual screen.

Comment: Where does navigation come from in your custom header button? You should get it passed in to the component.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your reference of `props.navigation.goBack()` inside `StackC`. This reference is passed to `StackC2` from the Tab navigator. From the perspective of the Tab, the last screen you visited in the Tab was A1, so the `navigation` reference that originated from the Tab brings you back to A1.

I didn't find a perfect solution to that. The workaround I found was to get a reference of the navigation container above all these navigators:

`<NavigationContainer ref={RootNavigation.navigationRef} />`

and then use `const navigation = RootNavigation.navigationRef.current` inside `StackC`.

```
export const StackC = () => {
   // Do not use the reference props.navigation, as it will jump all the way back outside this whole stack
  const navigation = RootNavigation.navigationRef.current;
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
    headerLeft: props => <HeaderBackButton {...props} 
      onPress={() => navigation?.goBack()} 
    />
}}
    initialRouteName="C1"
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="C1" component={ScreenC1}  />
      <Stack.Screen name="C2" component={ScreenC2} />
      <Stack.Screen name="C3" component={ScreenC3} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

In this way, when I navigate to from Screen A1 -> C1 -> C2 and use navigation.goBack(), I will correctly reverse the path, getting C2 -> C1 -> A1.

I am sorry since using a global ref is a not the best coding pattern, but I didn't find a more robust solution for my need.